# Ubuntu 15.10 desktop freezes upon login

Tags: unity, gnome, 15.10, compiz, freeze

So I've been using this distro(with Unity user interface) for a couple of months, and I decided to set up the LAMP and even use vsftpd for my wordpress website. However today I've encounter first serious trouble. When I login I see no icons, I can't open terminal... basically only thing I can do is to move a mouse cursor.

I've followed some of good ideas and good the guidelines in removing such as:

> dconf reset -f /org/compiz
>
> setsid unity

[or this one, which I thought that would actually solve my problem because according to the description of the problem is the same as mine](https://askubuntu.com/questions/17381/unity-doesnt-load-no-launcher-no-dash-appears)

so please if you got any clue about it, it would be appreciated

**EDIT:**
Also I tried switching from Unity to Gnome, following [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/708661/can-i-remove-unity-and-ubuntu-desktop-and-still-get-release-updates-upgrades) thread, but it didn't work, I have black-ish screen upon login, kind of the same problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I didn't manage to find solution to my problem so I reinstalled Ubuntu 15.10 and did the backup. [This guide helped me](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UbuntuReinstallation). And it works, even before I did backup I could preserve all of my files inside my home folder, but I had small trouble with USB mouse and keyboard(I use laptop).